# WP E Commerce Safe Mode restriction error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have my online shop, created with WP Ecommerce getting broken after I moved it to another server. I could be sure that the problem comes from WP Ecommerce because when I disable that plugin. Everything run as expected. This is the exact error message

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid is 515 is not allowed to access /tmp owned by uid 0 in /home/mikalu/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-core/wpsc-constants.php on line 17

Fatal error: session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Failed to initialize storage module: files (path: ) in /home/mikalu/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-core/wpsc-constants.php on line 17
```

I've tried to turn off safe mode on my php configuration. nothing happens. the error's still there.

I thought it was some kind of permission issue, so I tried to change /tmp permission to 777. Nothing happens. I googled it some more and suspect it might have something to do with fastCGI configuration and stuff. Which I totally don't understand.

My googling result mostly suggest me to consult the web hosting provider or even to move to another host. But in this case, I am the owner of the server (VPS with cPanel/WHM). And I don't have any idea how to solve this kind of problem

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

**edit:** I'm not so sure of this is really a server issue. Because if it really server configuration issue on session save path. Then the whole wordpress shouldn't be working coz it obviously use some session too. The session problem only come from that particular wp-ecommerce script. That's why I post it here on stackoverflow too.

Comment: Try [webmasters.stackexchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: That's a server configuration issue, please contact your hoster and solve the issue with their support as this is related to specific server configuration.

Comment: @Max: okay, I've posted it on that site too http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28899/wp-e-commerce-safe-mode-restriction-error

Comment: @hakre: don't you read my entire question... I am the owner of the server

Answer (score 0):

After your edit, it's more clear why you ask that question. Wordpress itself does not uses PHP session, so it's not causing the issue but those component you're using is using PHP sessions.

The PHP manual normally is a good start to understand safemode and how to disable it: http://php.net/manual/features.safe-mode.php

Additionally you should review your server configuration that it is safe instead. Safe-mode is unsafe. Hopefully your server ain't.

Comment: ohoho... I just realize wordpress doesn't use session at all. anyway, regarding my problem, I think it's better for me to find a solution how to make the /tmp (session save path) accessible to the script. Instead of just disabling the safe mode. do you have any clue about how to do that?

Comment: Why not change the session save path to a directory owned by that user instead: http://php.net/manual/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path ? For safe mode configuration see the link above, already posted it, if that's too much over your head this alternative suggestion is probably better fitting your needs.